# Django - show loading message with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I need help please,

I'm using Paramiko to send command to my virtual machine, so as it takes some time I want to tell the user to please wait for a moment. I want to show a message when I hit a button on my `td`. I'm not really familiar with front-end to be honest I was trying to do a `jquery` to make it work.

this is my div:

```
<div id="loading" class="alert alert-info" style="display:none;">Please, wait...</div>
```

that's what I want to show when the button is clicked.

My td:

```
<td  id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom" ><a id="paramiko" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" title="paramiko" href="{% url 'paramiko_function' item.id %}"><span class="fa fa-signal"></span> </a> </td>
```

as you can see I got a button that when I hit on that it will run my `paramiko_function` and make the process.

This is my JS:

```
$("td").submit(function() {
{
  if( $("[a_pressed]").get(0) === undefined )
  { 
    $('#loading').show();
  }
}
return true;    
});

$(":a").live('click', function() {
   $(this).attr("a_pressed", $(this).val());
});
```

what I was trying to do is when that `td` is pressed show my `div` with the message but that's not working.

Hope you could help me.
**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: How long do you want them to wait? Will it always be a fixed time (say 3 seconds)? Are you making any AJAX call?

Comment: 8 seconds would be fine. I really want to show msg when button is pressed. @nik_m